# Merging nested dictionary's to Json file for d3 sunburst

Tags: json, python-3.x, merge, nested

The problem i'm having is that I need a list of small heavily nested dictionary's to merge into a single one. all the small dictionary's have the exact same layout

```
{
"name": "root",
"tax": "Tax level: domain",
"children": [
    {
        "name": "Bacteria",
        "tax": "Tax level: Kingdom",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Firmicutes",
                "tax": "Tax level: Phylum",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Bacillidae",
                        "tax": "Tax level: Class",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "Bacillinae",
                                "tax": "Tax level: Order",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Bacillini",
                                        "tax": "Tax level: Family",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "Bacillus",
                                                "tax": "Tax level: Genus",
                                                "children": [
                                                    {
                                                        "name": "",
                                                        "size": 5,
                                                        "tax": "Tax level: Species"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Different solutions tried only merged the first dictionary; the "name": "root" and got me this result:

```
{
"name": "root",
"tax": "Tax level: domain",
"children": [
    {
        "name": "Bacteria",
        "tax": "Tax level: Kingdom",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Firmicutes",
                "tax": "Tax level: Phylum",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Bacillidae",
                        "tax": "Tax level: Class",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "Bacillinae",
                                "tax": "Tax level: Order",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Bacillini",
                                        "tax": "Tax level: Family",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "Bacillus",
                                                "tax": "Tax level: Genus",
                                                "children": [
                                                    {
                                                        "name": "",
                                                        "size": 5,
                                                        "tax": "Tax level: Species"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Bacteria",
        "tax": "Tax level: Kingdom",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Thermotogae",
                "tax": "Tax level: Phylum",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Thermotogae",
                        "tax": "Tax level: Class",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "Thermotogales",
                                "tax": "Tax level: Order",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Thermotogaceae",
                                        "tax": "Tax level: Family",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "Thermotoga",
                                                "tax": "Tax level: Genus",
                                                "children": [
                                                    {
                                                        "name": "",
                                                        "size": 5,
                                                        "tax": "Tax level: Species"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

But what I need is the duplicates to get removed and the other lines to be appended. Like this below (done manually):

```
{
"name": "root",
"tax": "Tax level: domain",
"children": [
    {
        "name": "Bacteria",
        "tax": "Tax level: Kingdom",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Firmicutes",
                "tax": "Tax level: Phylum",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Bacillidae",
                        "tax": "Tax level: Class",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "Bacillinae",
                                "tax": "Tax level: Order",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Bacillini",
                                        "tax": "Tax level: Family",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "Bacillus",
                                                "tax": "Tax level: Genus",
                                                "children": [
                                                    {
                                                        "name": "",
                                                        "size": 5,
                                                        "tax": "Tax level: Species"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Firmicutes",
                                "tax": "Tax level: Class",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Tissierellia",
                                        "tax": "Tax level: Order",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "unclassified Tissierellia",
                                                "tax": "Tax level: Family",
                                                "children": [
                                                    {
                                                        "name": "Tepidimicrobium",
                                                        "tax": "Tax level: Genus",
                                                        "children": [
                                                            {
                                                                "name": "",
                                                                "size": 5,
                                                                "tax": "Tax level: Species"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Thermotogae",
                "tax": "Tax level: Phylum",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Thermotogae",
                        "tax": "Tax level: Class",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "Thermotogales",
                                "tax": "Tax level: Order",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Thermotogaceae",
                                        "tax": "Tax level: Family",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "Thermotoga",
                                                "tax": "Tax level: Genus",
                                                "children": [
                                                    {
                                                        "name": "",
                                                        "size": 5,
                                                        "tax": "Tax level: Species"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Code I have written accepts a dictionary list and sends them one by one to a merge module that merges dictionary's.

```
tempCount = -1                                                                      #initializes Counter for dictionary, starts at -1 to compensate index errors.
try:
    for i in tempDicts:                                                             #Loops over list with small dictionarys
        tempCount += 1                                                              #Adds to the counter
        if tempCount <=0:                                                           #if the counter is 0, it adds the first and second dictionary to a merged dictionary
            result = merge(tempDicts[tempCount], tempDicts[tempCount+1])
        elif tempCount > 0:                                                         #if the counter is higher than 0, it merges the small dictionary to the already merged dictionary.
            result = merge(result, tempDicts[tempCount+1])
        else:
            print("Error in merging temporary dictionarys!")                        #catches random errors.
    print("test")
    print(result)
    print(reduce(result))

except IndexError:                                                                  #catches index out of range errors.
    print("Finished Merging")                                                       #if there are no more small dicts to merge, it gets an error and stops.
```

Comment: You might want to reduce the size of example of nested dictionary, we get the idea

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i want to see your style for solving this question

Comment: Its too hard looking through your dictionary. Could you perhaps shrink it to a smaller one?

Comment: @RoadRunner I'm afraid I cant, the dictionary's need to be static at this identation.

Answer (score 0):

With [RFC 7386](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386), we have JSON merge.
And just extend the JSON merge with a special process for arrays.

```
def merge_patch(target, patch, arraykey="name"):
    if isinstance(patch, dict):
        if not isinstance(target, dict):
            target = {}
        for name, value in patch.items():
            if value is None and name in target:
                del target[name]
            else:
                if name in target:
                    target[name] = merge_patch(target[name], value, arraykey)
                else:
                    target[name] = value
        return target
    elif isinstance(patch, list):
        if not isinstance(target, list):
            target = []
        dicted_target = {item[arraykey]:item for item in target}
        dicted_patch = {item[arraykey]:item for item in patch}
        for name, value in dicted_patch.items():
            if value is None and name in dicted_target:
                del dicted_target[name]
            else:
                if name in target:
                    dicted_target[name] = merge_patch(dicted_target[name], value, arraykey)
                else:
                    dicted_target[name] = value
        return list(dicted_target.values())
    else:
        return patch

print(merge_patch('x', 'y'))
print(merge_patch({'a':1},{'b':2}))
print(merge_patch([{'name':'a','x':'z'},{'name':'b'}],[{'name':'a','x':'y'},{'name':'c'}]))
```

And there we have. Notice that target will be mutated by the function (require some work to make it pure function).

Comment: Getting an error after importing the repository on the pairs() function.
`File "XMLtoJSON.py", line 146, in merge_patch
    for name, value in patch.pairs():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pairs'`

Comment: Some mistakes fixed